# Find circle objects (stamps) in document image Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I wrote a simple code to search for circles in documents (since seals have a rounded shape).

But due to the poor image quality, the print outline is fuzzy, and opencv cannot always detect it. I edited the picture in photoshop and enhanced the dark colors. I saved the picture and sent it for processing. It helped me. Opencv has identified a circle representing a low-quality print (there are no such problems in high-quality documents). My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r"C:\buh\doc.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# I tried experimenting with bluer, but opencv doesn't see circles in this case
# blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray.copy(), 15, 15, 15 )
# imS = cv2.resize(blurred, (960, 540))
# cv2.imshow('img', imS)
# cv2.waitKey(0)



minDist = 100
param1 = 30 #500
param2 = 100 #200 #smaller value-> more false circles
minRadius = 90
maxRadius = 200 #10

# docstring of HoughCircles: HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) -> circles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Show result for testing:
imS = cv2.resize(img, (960, 540))
cv2.imshow('img', imS)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The seals in the documents are circles as in the photo:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot add photo of the document where the original seals are located, since this is a private information...

So, I need to enhance the shades of black in the photo before trying to look for circles. How can I do this? I would also listen to other suggestions for improving the contours of seals (stamps), if someone has already encountered this.

Thank you.

Example:

[image]

Comment: If the problem is that the circles aren't connected, you could try to extract the seals by using color filtering (if they always have the same color). Then by dilating the contours to fill the gaps. I think the gaps also shouldn't be too big for this to work.

Comment: @Epsi Unfortunately, the circles are not always the same color. They can be black\blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, convert to [grayscale](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/stable/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html), [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering), then [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization).
2. **Merge small contours into a single large contour.** We dilate using [`cv2.dilate`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) to merge circles into a single contour.
3. **Find external contours.** Finally we [find external contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) with the external `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` flag and [`cv2.drawContours()`](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html)

---

Visualization of the image pipeline

Input image

[image]

Threshold for binary image

[image]

Dilate

[image]

Detected contours in green

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsus threshold, dilate
image = cv2.imread('3.PNG')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Tell me, please, some stamps are of poor quality and their contours are blurred. In this case, nothing can be done with the image? I added a photo as an example to my main post. The stamp on the left is of high quality and with clear contours. It is defined by opencv. While the print on the right has fuzzy contours.

Comment: Depending on the image you may have to 1) adjust the kernel size, 2) change the number of dilation iterations, or 3) do contour area filtering to isolate larger sized contours. Take a look at [morphological operations](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) for other things you could do

Comment: thank you very much! Tell me, please, can I isolate contours of a certain size and increase them using this [code](https://answers.opencv.org/question/65005/in-python-how-can-i-reduce-a-list-of-contours-to-those-of-a-specified-size/)? I'm sorry for the stupid question, I'm just new to python and don't quite understand how to do it

Comment: Yup that should work, `cv2.contourArea` to filter out contours